# AngularJS search criteria based on two inputs

Tags: angularjs, gridview, angularjs-filter

I am designing an application to do some CRUD operations related to the database. As part of my application i am trying to implement a search based on two inputs one is a dropdown/combo box and the other one is an input. 
As soon as user enters finishes entering the text into the text then hit search ,  it should fetch all the information related to that particular record and populate that in the textboxes

Not able to handle the search with both the inputs. Any help is appreciated.

This is

```js
var myapp = angular.module("myModule", []);
myapp.controller("myController", function($scope){
 
 var listProducts = [
  { id: '100', name: "Macy", price: 200, quantity: 2 },
  { id: '100', name: "Macy", price: 100, quantity: 1 },
  { id: '101', name: "JCPenny", price: 400, quantity: 1 },
  { id: '102', name: "Primark", price: 300, quantity: 3 },
  { id: '103', name: "H&M", price: 600, quantity: 1 }
 ];
 
 $scope.listProducts = listProducts;
 
 $scope.del = function(id){
  var txt = confirm("Are you sure??")
   if (txt==true){
    var index = getSelectedIndex(id);
    $scope.listProducts.splice(index,1);
   }
  
 };
 
 $scope.selectEdit = function(id){
  var index = getSelectedIndex(id);
  var product = $scope.listProducts[index];
  $scope.id=product.id;
  $scope.name=product.name;
  $scope.price=product.price;
  $scope.quantity=product.quantity;
 };
 
// $scope.searchproduct= function(item){
//  var product = 
// }
 
 function getSelectedIndex(id){
  for(i=0; i<$scope.listProducts.length; i++)
   if($scope.listProducts[i].id == id)
    return i;
  return -1;
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">

  <head>
    
    <script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myController">
    ID: 
    <select ng-model=search>
   <option ng-repeat="products in listProducts">{{products.id}}</option>
  </select>
  
  Quantity:
  <input>
  <div>
    <button ng-click="selectEdit(search)">search</button>  
  </div>
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Edit Information </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>ID</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="id"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Price</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="price"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Quantity</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="quantity"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <input type="button" value="Add" />
      <input type="button" value="Save"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody> 
  </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Click here for my Plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/KvVTvaCtPeFKJcPSnGYQ?p=preview

Comment: Your Plunker is not working.

Comment: @JPDolocanog changed the plunker link . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an object for the search parameters. You can store input from the combo in `search.id` and input from the text input in `search.quantity`

```
<select ng-model="search.id">
    <option ng-repeat="products in listProducts">{{products.id}}</option>
</select>
Quantity:
<input type="text" ng-model="search.quantity">
```

In the `selectEdit` function you will filter by the search object.

```
$scope.selectEdit = function(){
    var index = getSelectedIndex($scope.search);
    ...
}
```

And `getSelectedIndex` will look like this

```
function getSelectedIndex(search){
    for(i=0; i<$scope.listProducts.length; i++)
        if($scope.listProducts[i].id == search.id && $scope.listProducts[i].quantity == search.quantity)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

See the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BZDCwiYyakXddVQ3Hu9U?p=preview)

Comment: i understood foreach but i am not able to make necessary  changes in the function selectEdit to display the data in the respective fields                                                              https://plnkr.co/edit/KvVTvaCtPeFKJcPSnGYQ?p=preview      Please help me with that function. Thanks in advance

Comment: @annie updated my unswer to use regular `for` and link for a plunker

Comment: data is not populating into the fields.  Thanks in advance

Comment: thank you so much davekr. It is working for me. I will try to implement that in my application